# Dropdown is getting hidden under Navbar in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, styled-components

I am having two Navbars, the Top Navbar has a dropdown for choosing website language and the Bottom navbar is for general purposes.
I gave `background-color: white;` to the bottom Navbar and when I choose the dropdown, the contents of the Dropdown are getting hidden or behind the bottom one. Here is the image:
[image]

When I remove the CSS property of `background-color`, I am able to see the Dropdown contents, but the contents are getting behind the Bottom Navbar not overlapping in front of it as it is supposed to be. Here is the image:
[image]

This is my Bottom Navbar code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar, Form, Image, Container, InputGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from 'src/assets/vectors/logo.svg';
import accountIcon from 'src/assets/vectors/profileicon.svg';
import cartIcon from 'src/assets/vectors/carticon-empty.svg';
import searchIcon from 'src/assets/vectors/searchicon.svg';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Navb = styled(Navbar)`
  margin-top: 28px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  font-weight: 700;
`;
const NavigationBar = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navb variant="light" fixed="top" expand="lg" className="pt-4 pb-4">
                <Container>
                    <Navb.Brand href="/" className="d-none d-lg-block"><Image src={logo}></Image></Navb.Brand>
                    {/* some "mobile only" handling (burger menu, centered logo, search icon on the left, etc.) */}
                    <Navb.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                    <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/" className="mr-auto d-lg-none ml-4"><Image src={searchIcon}></Image></Nav.Link>
                    <Navb.Brand href="/" className="mr-auto d-lg-none"><Image src={logo}></Image></Navb.Brand>
                    <Navb.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="mr-auto">
                            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/" className="nav-2 ml-xl-4">Home</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link className="nav-2 ml-xl-4">Shop</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link className="nav-2 ml-xl-4">Sale</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav>
                        <Form inline className="d-none d-lg-block mr-4 search-control">
                            <InputGroup>
                                <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend"
                                />
                                <InputGroup.Prepend>
                                    <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroupPrepend"><Image src={searchIcon} ></Image></InputGroup.Text>
                                </InputGroup.Prepend>
                            </InputGroup>
                        </Form>
                    </Navb.Collapse>
                    <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/"><Image src={accountIcon}></Image></Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/cart" className="pr-0"><Image src={cartIcon}></Image></Nav.Link>
                </Container>
            </Navb>
        </>
    );
}
```

export default NavigationBar;

This is the Top LanguageSwitch Navbar:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavDropdown, Navbar, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Flex from "./flex";

export type eventKey = string | null;

const LanguageNav = () => {
     const [language, setLanguage] = React.useState<eventKey>("DE");
     const [currency, setCurrency] = React.useState<eventKey>("€ EUR");

     const handleLanguageChange = React.useCallback((eventKey: eventKey) => {
          setLanguage(eventKey);
          if(eventKey == "DE")
               setCurrency("€ EUR");
          else if(eventKey == "JP")
               setCurrency("¥ JPY");
          else if(eventKey == "US")
               setCurrency("$ USD");
          else
               setCurrency("£ GBP");
     }, []);

     const handleCurrencyChange = React.useCallback((eventKey: eventKey) => {
          setCurrency(eventKey);
          if(eventKey == "€ EUR")
               setLanguage("DE");
          else if(eventKey == "¥ JPY")
               setLanguage("JP");
          else if(eventKey == "$ USD")
               setLanguage("US");
          else
               setLanguage("UK");
     }, []);

     return (
          <>
               <Navbar className="navbar-top" fixed="top">
                    <Container>
                         <Flex justify="flex-end" padding="0 20px 0 0">
                              <NavDropdown
                                   onSelect={handleLanguageChange}
                                   alignRight
                                   title={language}
                                   id="basic-nav-dropdown"
                              >
                                   <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="US">US</NavDropdown.Item>
                                   <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="UK">UK</NavDropdown.Item>
                                   <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="DE">DE</NavDropdown.Item>
                                   <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="JP">JP</NavDropdown.Item>
                              </NavDropdown>
                              <NavDropdown
                                   onSelect={handleCurrencyChange}
                                   alignRight
                                   title={currency}
                                   id="basic-nav-dropdown"
                              >
                                   <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="€ EUR">€ EUR</NavDropdown.Item>
                                   <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="£ GBP">£ GBP</NavDropdown.Item>
                                   <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="¥ JPY">¥ JPY</NavDropdown.Item>
                                   <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="$ USD">$ USD</NavDropdown.Item>
                              </NavDropdown>
                         </Flex>
                    </Container>
               </Navbar>
          </>
     );
};

export default LanguageNav;
```

Am I missing anything here? Any CSS property to be taken care of?

Comment: If your components LanguageNav and NavigationBar are in the same div, so you have to explicitly specify `position: relative` for both. Then set `z-index` with a higher value for  LanguageNav.

Comment: No, they are not a div actually, and also they are separately connected.